# Searching for an Email client compatible with Percussion CMS which also has user account management capabilites

Tags: content-management-system, email, user-accounts, email-client, account-management

We're transitioning our site to a new content management system called Percussion. We're looking for a 3rd party email client to integrate. We're also hoping the email client allows for user account management and permissions.

Has anyone:

1) Used Percussion CMS and integrated any email clients? Which ones and how did they work?
2) Does anyone know of an email client which also allows you to manage user accounts and accessibility (that also hopefully integrates with Percussion)?

Sidenote: mail chimp and imodules are already ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still researching this question? I personally know/understand Percussion CM1 extremely well. I handle most/all tech support for the product.

This question would really depend on the focus of your "email". If it was purely for Marketing purposes, the tool would not offer you this sort of functionality in its present stage.

However, if you are looking for a way to notify people internally that someone has filled out information through a  or pages have transitioned in some type of work flow status, then yes, Percussion could email you. There is some light configurations for LDAP and your SMTP server to handle these sort of things internally.

Thinking outside of the box, one could create an HTML page with the tool, and possibly copy/paste it into an email. But this would probably defeat the point.

To give you an idea, our company internally uses a combination of HubSpot and Elloqua to handle most of this tracking/email notifications.

Talk to your sales rep/engineer if you have more questions about its functionality. Hopefully this helped.

Chris